# чтение текстового файла и работа с ним c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

дан файл f,содержащий сведения о кубиках : размер каждого кубика(длина ребра),его цвет(красный,желтый) и материал(деревянный,пластмассовый)
найти:
количество кубиков каждого из перечисленных цветов и их суммарный объем

помогите кто-нибудь,Спасибо

я смог сделать вот так,но программа считывает только строки с найденным словом,а как посчитать объем кубов,я не пойму:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            label1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;                
            f_open = true;                
            richTextBox1.Clear();               
            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);                
            string line = null;
            string inf = "plastmassoviy";              
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("plastmassoviy"))                            
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(line);                      
                     richTextBox1.AppendText("\r");                        
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            {
            }
            StreamReader sr1 = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            line = null;
            line = sr1.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                {                        
                    richTextBox2.AppendText(line);                        
                    richTextBox2.AppendText("\r\n");                       
                    line = sr1.ReadLine();
                }
            }                
            sr.Close();
            sr1.Close();      

        }
введите сюда код
```

Comment: я смог сделать вот так,но программа считывает только строки с найденным словом,а как посчитать объем кубов,я не пойму:

Comment: Переведите код в текст, пожалуйста

Comment: Miron, добавил код

Comment: желательно еще и текст задачи перевести в текст

Comment: исправил,помогите пожалуйста,если можно

Comment: Из каждой полученной строчки получаете строну куба. Прибавляете ее куб(3 степень) к сумме(изначально = 0). Проблемы с парсом строки?

Comment: я просто не очень в этом разбираюсь,и не знаю как получить сторону куба со строки,и как складывать эти строки

Comment: Вам следует сначала изучить строки. Серьезно, ответ сейчас - это медвежья услуга. Помочь лично я вам с этим не могу, так как я джавист.

Comment: так мне и нужна медвежья услуга,просто это лабораторная работа,я ее сдам и забуду,оно мне не надо,к сожалению

Comment: можно увидеть пример файла?

Comment: файл не так важен,просто .txt

Comment: примерное содержание:
red plastmassa 1
red plastmassa 2
red plastmassa 3
green iron 3
blue wood 2
yellow karton 4

Answer (score 0):

Разбиваете строку на слова с помощью метода Split(). далее создаете массив из таких массивов.А лучше List

```
float sumVol;
List<string[3]> coubs = new List<string[3];
StreamReader sr1 = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
line = null;
line = sr1.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    {  
         coubs.Add(line.Split(" "));             
         richTextBox2.AppendText(line);                        
         richTextBox2.AppendText("\r\n");                       
         line = sr1.ReadLine();
    }
}                
sr1.Close();
foreach(string[3] coub in coubs)
{
    int lenght = int.Parse(coub[2]);
    sumVol+=(lenght*lenght*leght); // Это и есть суммарный объем кубов, выводите его 
                                   // куда вам нужно
}
```